# Is there a way to view Python API documentation from within code?

Tags: python

I am looking for a Python IDE that will display the API (standard or third party module) documentations as pop-up when I hover over the code e.g. in eclipse if you hover over the java code it will give you the details of the functions or class, given the API documentation is setup in your IDE.

I can access the documentation from the respective web-site, but this not what I am looking for.

I am using PyCharm Community version, but could not find a way to see the documentation as quick view, also trying to find out if they support such feature at all. Anyone has any experience with any other IDE that will support such feature other than Eclipse.

TIA.

Comment: Python extension from VSCode can achieve that, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @Vulpex thanks. you got it exactly. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code Python extension has a feature that will show the documentation of a documented code. Juts type the name of a function or a class and choose the one you want from the autocomplete list.

**For example:**

[image: example]

Here on the right you can see the code documentation. You can scroll down in that window to see all.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what I was looking for.